# user input inside awk -- or -- variable usage in search pattern

Tags: variables, search, input, awk

I'm trying to take a user input in a pure [g]awk code. now the requirement is that I want the user to enter either today or current - number of days to generate a report.  I can't find any routine inside the awk to read user's input. sometime back I had read a document on awk where it was done using either sprintf or printf, but I dont know how.

OR

in awk, I'm using BEGIN block to setup a variable and then search based on that, but not finding it quite helpful to search the variable based search. something like below:

```
awk -F "|" ' BEGIN { PWR="Nov  3"; }
/Deployment started at PWR/ { print $1 + $NF }' /var/log/deployments
```

this offensively denies me any search for the pattern of "Deployment started at Nov  3".

Answer (score 0):

Inside the regex slashes, you don't have access to your variables.  What you can do is make a string out of the search phrase then *apply* that string as a regex.

```
awk -F "|" ' BEGIN { PWR="Nov  3"; }
$0 ~ "Deployment started at "PWR { print $1 + $NF }' /var/log/deployments
```

Comment: That's pretty [unnecessarily] fragile. I'd use a string comparison instead: `index($0,"Deployment started at "PWR)`. Hopefully the white space in the setting of PWR eliminates false matches of `Nov 3` against `Nov 30`.